# How do I "show" my UV Map after loading a new image?

Tags: uv, interface

I've had this happen to me several times. I'm using the UV Map tech perfectly fine. Then I need to load another image. I load the new image, and now my UV Map overlay disappears and the new image is in its place with no mesh.

I've looked all over the web, and I can't find the command to go back to the mesh overlay of my UV Map within the UV Map window.

Help!

Comment: If you leave Keep UV and Mesh selection in sync option disabled then (as by default) mesh has to in Edit mode and all selected to see UV map. If you enable that option the UV map will be shown regardless and selection / editing will be synced between UV editor and viewport

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this to show the gif below. This should not happen, imho. You enter the mesh edit mode, and in the UV/image editor, you see the uvmap and the current mapped image. Then, you simply select another image.

[image]

Comment: I think I found the toggle for my situation. When I first lost it, I selected UV local mode, and that kept it from showing up. Thank you! Your GIF helped!